# Do really need to send app for review on facebook when using Facebook php sdk 4.0?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Upgrading facebook php sdk 3.0 (graph api 1.0)  to facebook php sdk 4.0 (graph api 2.2).

I have made app in Facebook for feature "facebook login".

system working fine with sdk 3.0.

Now I am going to upgrade to facebook php sdk 4.0.

So, my question is:

**Do I really need to send app for review on facebook when using Facebook php sdk 4.0?**

Is it compulsory?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review?locale=en_GB

Comment: Sverri, Thanks for link, 

But Don't found any clear instruction that, whether its compulsory to submit app for review or not?

Does feature works well, if I don't submit app for review?

Comment: Just because you use SDK 4.0 doesn't mean you have to submit for review. You can read at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login when you need to submit for review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using the app, just for the authentication part it is not necessary to submit the app for review. but for accessing additional elements or special permissions, you will need to submit it for a review. read about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) .

> In order for your app to access additional elements of a person's
>   Facebook profile (**read permissions**) or to publish content to Facebook
>   on their behalf (**write permissions**), you will need to submit for
>   review.